# How to manipulate the reduce function in crossfilter in a way to create a certain array/object structure?

Tags: d3.js, reduce, crossfilter

I'm using crossfilter and am looking for a certain output after the reduce function:

```
var ndx = crossfilter(data);     
var alDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return d.al_code_unique; });
var seatsPaxAirline = alDim.group().reduce(
            function(a, d) {
                a.seats += d.seats;
                a.pax += d.pax;
                return a;
            },
            function(a, d) {
                a.seats -= d.seats;
                a.pax -= d.pax;
                return a;
            },
            function() {
                return  {seats:0, pax:0 }; }
            ).top(100);
```

seatsPaxAirline is now an array of objects like this:

```
[
{key: "5Y", value: {pax: 60, seats: 100}},
{key: "4Y", value: {pax: 50, seats: 90}},
{key: "3Y", value: {pax: 40, seats: 80}}
]
```

But I do need the following output from the crossfilter reduce function:

```
[
 {key: "5Y", value: [ {name: "pax", value: 60}, {name: "seats", value: 100}},
 {key: "4Y", value: [ {name: "pax", value: 50}, {name: "seats", value: 90}},
 {key: "3Y", value: [ {name: "pax", value: 40}, {name: "seats", value: 80}},
]
```

I feel it's just a question of changing the reduce function in a certain manner but unfortunately I have no clue. Could someone help me on this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand the question, you need to change your reduce function like so:

```
var seatsPaxAirline = alDim.group().reduce(
            function(a, d) {
                a[0].value += d.seats;
                a[1].value += d.pax;
                return a;
            },
            function(a, d) {
                a[0].value -= d.seats;
                a[1].value -= d.pax;
                return a;
            },
            function() {
                return  [{name: 'seats', value: 0}, {name: 'pax', value: 0}]; }
            ).top(100);
```

The key is in how you set up the reduceInitial function, as that will determine the data structure of your 'a' object that gets passed through the reduce.

Comment: Hey, thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for. This will also help me in the future.

Comment: Also on an unrelated note, I noticed you're using top(100), which might not behave as expected using this type of array reduction. E.g. to order by seats, you may need to set a custom order function like so: 

function orderValue(p) {
  return p[0].value;
}

var seatsPaxAirline = alDim.group().reduce(...).order(orderValue).top(100)

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, your input format is similar to:

```
var seatsPaxAirline = 
    [{key: "5Y", value: {pax: 60, seats: 100}},
     {key: "5Y", value: {pax: 40, seats: 100}},
     {key: "3Y", value: {pax: 30, seats: 100}},
     {key: "2Y", value: {pax: 70, seats: 100}},
     {key: "4Y", value: {pax: 50, seats: 100}},
     {key: "1Y", value: {pax: 45, seats: 100}},
     {key: "2Y", value: {pax: 50, seats: 100}},
     {key: "5Y", value: {pax: 60, seats: 100}},
     {key: "5Y", value: {pax: 65, seats: 100}},
     {key: "5Y", value: {pax: 55, seats: 100}}
     ];
```

And, you wish to group elements based on their key values like:

```
{
    "5Y": [{"key": "5Y", "value": {"pax": 60, "seats": 100}},
           {"key": "5Y", "value": {"pax": 40, "seats": 100}}, 
           {"key": "5Y", "value": {"pax": 60, "seats": 100}}, 
           {"key": "5Y", "value": {"pax": 65, "seats": 100}}, 
           {"key": "5Y", "value": {"pax": 55, "seats": 100}}],
    "3Y": [{"key": "3Y", "value": {"pax": 30, "seats": 100}}],
    "2Y": [{"key": "2Y", "value": {"pax": 70, "seats": 100}},
           {"key": "2Y", "value": {"pax": 50, "seats": 100}}],
    "4Y": [{"key": "4Y", "value": {"pax": 50, "seats": 100}}],
    "1Y": [{"key": "1Y", "value": {"pax": 45, "seats": 100}}]
}
```

If this is what you are looking to achieve using D3 then this is the way to do it:

```
d3.nest().key(function(d){return d.key}).map(seatsPaxAirline);
```

And, [**here's the working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/srvikram13/ckw8X/).

---

**EDIT:**
I believe the sample object you've provided is malformed. But, if you modify the code I provided as shown below:

```
var output = d3.nest().key(function(d){return d.key}).map(seatsPaxAirline);
d3.entries(d3.entries(output).forEach(function(d,i){
  d.value.forEach(function(o,j){ 
    delete o["key"];
    d.value[j] = d3.entries(o.value);
  });
}));
output = d3.entries(output);
```

The output you'll get is:

```
[{
  "key": "5Y",
  "value": [
    [{"key": "pax","value": 60}, {"key": "seats","value": 100}],
    [{"key": "pax","value": 40}, {"key": "seats","value": 100}],
    [{"key": "pax","value": 60}, {"key": "seats","value": 100}],
    [{"key": "pax","value": 65}, {"key": "seats","value": 100}],
    [{"key": "pax","value": 55}, {"key": "seats","value": 100}]
  ]
}, {
  "key": "3Y",
  "value": [
    [{"key": "pax","value": 30}, {"key": "seats","value": 100}]
  ]
}, {
  "key": "2Y",
  "value": [
    [{"key": "pax","value": 70}, {"key": "seats","value": 100}],
    [{"key": "pax","value": 50}, {"key": "seats","value": 100}]
  ]
}, {
  "key": "4Y",
  "value": [
    [{"key": "pax","value": 50}, {"key": "seats","value": 100}]
  ]
}, {
  "key": "1Y",
  "value": [
    [{"key": "pax","value": 45}, {"key": "seats","value": 100}]
  ]
}]
```

This is as close as I can get it to the desired data structure. See if this is usable for you.

[**Updated Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ckw8X/2/)

*PS: I realize that this isn't the most efficient of solutions but this is as good as it gets with me & D3. If you wish to fool around with the data structure, consider using [underscoreJS](http://underscorejs.org/).*

Comment: Sorry, maybe I was a little bit too short in explaining the object/array structure. I have made some clarifications above. I wast to modify the crossfilter output as described above. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what you want because your example isn't quite right (is "paxOnDep" supposed to just be "pax"?). But the question that comes to my mind is: why do you want to do this? It seems like you're just re-encoding the result object into an Array, but it's not clear to me what this buys you.

Comment: Yes, your are right: paxOnDep means pax - I changed it in the example. It's also true that I just need to re-encode the result. The reason is that I need to use the crossfilter result for a grouped D3 row chart. DC.js for instance doesn't support this type of chart. The way I want the output to look allows me a maximum of flexibility when creating the d3 grouped chart.

Comment: Thanks for your commitment and the offered solution. After revising everything, I realised that I mixed up dimensions and measures and thus you are right saying that my exmaple is somehow malfomrmed. Nevertheless, for me a good finding. Thanks again.